# Have JUnit fail tests that don't actually run an assertion

Tags: testing, junit

My team is working on educating some of our developers about testing. They understand why to write tests and are on board that they should write tests, but are falling a little short on writing good tests.

I just saw a commit like this

```
public void SomeTest{

@Test
public void testSomething{
 System.out.println(new mySomething.getData());
}
```

So they were at least making sure their code gave them the expected output by looking.

It will be a bit before we can really sell the idea of code reviews. In the mean time I was considering having JUnit fail any tests that do not have actual assertXXX or fail statements in them. I would then like to have that failure message say something like "Your tests should use assertions and actually examine the output!".

I fully expect this to lead to calls like `assertTrue(1 == 1);`. We're working on the team buy in for proper testing and code reviews, are there any technical mechanisms we can use to make life easier for the developers that already get it?? What about technical mechanisms to help the new guys understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some static code analyzer.

I use [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) which includes a [JUnit rule set](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/junit.html). There are a lot of [IDE plugins](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/integrations.html) which will mark rule violations in the IDE. You can configure the rule sets to your needs.

You will also profit from the other rule sets - which will warn you on code style / best practice violations (although you have to decide sometimes if the tool or you are the fool :-)).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider organizational changes: mentoring, training, code reviews.

The tools can only help you if you're using them in good faith with a base understanding of the goals. If one of these is missing they won't help you.

Humans are just to intelligent to do dump things or work around metrics. I think your assessment is not correct that "they" are on board if they can't write a single useful test. Automatic tools are simply not the correct tools at this stage. You can't learn by being told by a program what to do next.

Comment: I'm with you on getting people to buy in and get educated. I'm looking more for tools to help another developer and I monitor the the code so that when we spot a bad test we can flag it and go talk to the guys that are still learning.

Answer (score 0):

to answer the stated question for future viewers.

JUnit uses reflection to run tested function if any Exception, Error throws -> test fails, otherwise succeed. Assert class is just a utils class.